# Микросервисы и авторизация

Tags: авторизация, highload, микросервисы

Коллеги, доброго времени суток! Хотел поинтересоваться насчет авторизации в микросервисной архитектуре. Как я понял, мы пишем сервис Auth, который будет нас регистрировать и авторизировать. И в кажом сервисе где требуется авторизация - мы делаем запрос на сервис Auth::check(token). Получается если цепочка состоит из 5 сервисов, то мы делаем 5 запросов к сервису авторизации? не многова-то ли? или я не правильно что-то понимаю =)

Comment: Можно использовать не требующий запросов JWT, например

Comment: @andreymal точно, совсем забыл) спасибо :)